# How to compare uuid from MySQL binary(16) with Bigquery BYTES in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, google-bigquery, prisma

I have a database based on MySQL where I have UUIDs stored as Binary(16) and a Bigquery SQL database where the same UUIDs are stored as BYTES. I tried setting up this way to save space on both databases, but it turned out to be a little nightmare.

I'm using Prisma ORM to retrieve the UUID, which returns a Buffer type with the UUID string, then I need to query for that UUID on Bigquery. The only way I'm managing to do so is by converting both the BYTES field on Bigquery and the Buffer returned from MySQL to a hexadecimal string and comparing them together. But if I'm comparing UUIDs in hexadecimal strings, why bother to keep them on binary fields? Is there any way to compare the binaries without conversions?

```js
const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery')
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client')

const prisma = new PrismaClient()
const dataset = process.env.DB_DATASET
const tableClients = `(
  SELECT *, EXTRACT(DATE FROM insertion_time) ptt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uuid ORDER BY insertion_time desc) rn
  FROM \`${dataset}.clients\` WHERE insertion_time <= CURRENT_DATE() AND TO_HEX(parent_company_uuid) = @parent_company
) clients`

const projectId = 'my-project'
const keyFilename = process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery({
  projectId,
  keyFilename,
})

const TestService = {
  async test() {
    const company = await prisma.company.findFirst()
    const query = `SELECT * FROM ${tableClients} WHERE rn = 1 AND DATE(insertion_time) <= CURRENT_DATE()`
    const params = { parent_company: company.uuid.toString('hex') }
    const options = {
      query: `${query};`,
      params,
    }

    const [result] = await bigqueryClient.query(options)
    return result
  },
}

module.exports = TestService
```

The `tableClients` thing is because instead of updating the database (which Bigquery hates to) I'm inserting the same record with a new `insertion_time`, creating a partition based on this field, and getting the most recent record (row_number = 1). Also, I filter the company uuid there.

Comment: Tip: You don't need semi-colons when running queries programmatically, only when using an interactive shell. `query,` is fine, the `${query};` part is wasted effort.